# Cosmos DB Tables API Index PartitionKey & RowKey only

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

Using a TablesDB table in Cosmos DB I'm trying to index only the PartitionKey and RowKey.

My CosmosDB index below compiles correctly but when I run a query on the PartitionKey/RowKey I get the error "An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) excluded from indexing. Consider adding allow scan header in the request."

Does anyone know how to use CosmosDB TablesDB that indexes only the PartitionKey and RowKey and nothing else?

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/PartitionKey/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/RowKey/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the almost same index configuration, only changing the **'?'** character by **'*'**. Our configuration looks like this:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "lazy",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/PartitionKey/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/RowKey/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```